# I have syntax error on my code and I don't know what the problem is?

Tags: python, for-loop, file-handling

*Q: "Ask the user how many numbers they want to enter.  Let them enter this many numbers and write them to a text file. Each number must be on a separate line." I don't know what the error is*

```
user = int(input("how many numbers to enter"))
file = open("file1.txt" , "a")
for x in range(user):
    number = input("Enter number" + str(user + 1) + "\n")
    file.writelines(user+"\n")  
file.close()
```

Comment: I don't see any error, are you going to tell us what the problem is?

Comment: the `user` variable is used before its declaration and ``` should not be after `file.close()`

Comment: How is the `user` declared? What type is it?

Comment: the error is something with   str(? +1) + "\n")   and maybe   file.writelines(user+"\n")

Comment: @BeginnerCod3r Instead of guessing and having us guess, shown the full error with trace, edited into the question.

Comment: Should `str(user + 1)` be `str(x + 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the exercise order, I see you were close to the answer and assumed this is what you wanted.

```
user = int(input("How many numbers you want to enter?\n"))
file = open("file1.txt", "w")
for x in range(user):
    number = input("Enter number " + str(x + 1) + ":\n")
    file.writelines(str(x) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using your `user` variable instead of your `x` variable. The fixed code:

```
user = int(input("how many numbers to enter"))
with open("file1.txt" , "a") as file:
    for x in range(user):
        number = input("Enter number " + str(x + 1) + "\n")
        file.writelines(user + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the user variable and on row

```py
file.writelines(user+"\n")
```

you forgot to convert the int to a string.

```py
file.writelines(str(user)+"\n")
```

note your code is just going to write the user number "user" times.

Here is the edited code that works for me:

```py
user = 5 #number of users
file = open("file1.txt" , "a")
for x in range(user): #loop every user
    number = input("Enter number" + str(x + 1) + "\n") #Use "str()"" to convert number, called int, to a string 
    file.writelines(str(user) + "\n") 
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question was not clear to me, I presume this is what you expect.

```
user_input = int(input("how many numbers to enter:"))
with open("file1.txt" , "w") as output_file:
    for x in range(user_input):
        number = input("Enter number" + f'{x + 1}:' + "\n")
        print(number, file=output_file)
```

since `print` function itself does line carriage, you can omit adding new line.